# SQL server: invalid object name when creating stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc

JDBC connection:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:62621;databaseName=my_db
login: sa/123456
```

Try to create a stored procedure

```
CREATE or ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sp_drop_table_all_foreign_keys(...) AS
BEGIN
  ...
END;
```

Error:

```
Invalid object name dbo.sp_drop_table_all_foreign_keys
```

In SSMS: no problem.

Note: there is no user in the "my_db" created for the login "sa".

Comment: Not able to [reproduce your issue](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4ec09a08c7c41c8da84d3816502ed9d2).

Comment: On a side note, don't name stored procedures with prefix `sp_` as that is used to denote system stored procedures.

Comment: I assume you're either are connecting to the wrong DB, or created the Stored Procedure in the wrong DB. Also, having an application use the `sa` account is a bad idea. Create a `LOGIN` along with `USER`s with the minimal permissions needed by the application.